# What it the rails way to make dynamic forms? (Is the JQuery the only option?)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic-forms

I'm going to make form that:

1. Shows a message (text, object description) to rhe user
2. Shows a list of buttons. like 'comment', 'reroute' and 'close'.

3.1 If the user clicks on 'comment', shows text_area for input. The input is not for an attribute from a model, it must be later appended to the 'log' field.

3.2 If the user clicks on 'reroute', shows collection_select to choose to whom to reroute.

3.3 If the user clicks on 'close', shows text_area for input. The input must be later saved to the 'solution' field of the model.

What is the rails way to do this? Should I start learn the JQuery or there some gems instead of it? Or maybe I don't need nothind special and such a thing can be done with Rails alone?